# How to get the long region name with AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

How can one get the region name in AWS CDK?

Some SDKs provide Region objects (see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38020106/1736679))

Inside a CDK construct, `self.region` is available, and `cdk.aws_region` has a `RegionInfo` class, but it doesn't provide the name, eg: ap-southeast-1 -> Singapore

Comment: If it was available in CDK I think you'd find it in https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/region-info/lib/aws-entities.ts - it's not there right now but it looks to be a fairly simple addition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS exposes region long names (like `Asia Pacific (Singapore)` for `ap-southeast-1`) as [publicly available Parameter Store parameters](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-query-for-aws-regions-endpoints-and-more-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/).  Lookup this value at synth-time with [ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.StringParameter.html#static-valuewbrfromwbrlookupscope-parametername)<sup>*</sup>.  You need the region id for the parameter path, which a stack (or construct) can introspect.

```js
export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const regionLongName: string = ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup(
      this,
      `/aws/service/global-infrastructure/regions/${this.region}/longName`
    );

    console.dir({ region: this.region, regionLongName });
  }
}
```

For Python

```py
aws_cdk.aws_ssm.StringParameter.value_from_lookup(
            scope=self,
            parameter_name=f'/aws/service/global-infrastructure/regions/{self.region}/longName')
```

`cdk synth` output::

```js
{ region: 'us-east-1', regionLongName: 'US East (N. Virginia)' }
```

* The CDK's `valueFromLookup` [context method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html#context_methods) will cache the looked-up parameter store value in `cdk.context.json` at synth-time.  You may initially get a dummy value.  Just synth again.

Comment: Very interesting!